# How to search all the values in a dataframe with a particular string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am actually stuck and want to search a Dataframe to find all the cells which includes a url link into a different dataframe i.e.

**Input:**

```
             A    B            C
0            1    2  https://123
1  https://432  333           qq
2  https://567   rt           q4
```

**Output:**

```
             R
0  https://123
1  https://432
2  https://567
```

I am trying an approach to search all the columns containing the string "http" but its not working

Comment: What if there is more than one link in the same row? What if there is no link in a given row?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
output_df = pd.dataframe(columns=['R'])
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    output_df = pd.concat([ouput_df, df.loc[df[col].str.contains('https'), col].rename({col: 'R'}, axis=1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `stack()` your dataframe and use the method `contains()` to search for cells with urls:

```
df = df.stack()
df[df.str.contains('http')].to_frame('R').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
             R
0  https://123
1  https://432
2  https://567
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join each row by comma and use regex to find urls in each row, this works even there is multiple url. In case of no url it will set empty list for that row

```py
df.apply(lambda row: ",".join(row), axis=1).str.findall("http[s]?://[^,]*")
```